# Why aren't accentuated characters stored properly in my MySQL database?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, drupal-7, doctrine-orm

I have a drupal form which saves user input into a MySQL database using the Doctrine library. The problem is that if the user input has accentuated characters, they don't look good in the DB. For example, `Sempé` becomes `SempÃ©`. This is strange to me because:

- the field it is getting stored into is utf8: `varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,`
- the table is also utf8: `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=202 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci`
- all my php scripts, including the one which tells drupal what fields to add into the form) are saved as utf-8
- the form drupal creates accepts utf8: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/drupal/identification" method="post" id="form-identification" accept-charset="UTF-8">`
- the page drupal creates is sent as utf8: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
- the php->mysql connection is set to utf8:

  ```
  $dbParams = array("driver" => "pdo_mysql",
      "host" => variable_get("dbManip_host"),
      "user" => variable_get("dbManip_user"),
      "password" => variable_get("dbManip_password"),
      "dbname" => variable_get("dbManip_dbName"),
      "charset" => "utf8");
  ```

I also tried:

- adding `default_charset = "utf8"` to **php.ini**
- passing the form data in `utf8_encode` before saving it
- passing the form data in `mb_convert_encoding` before saving it

but none of those worked.

Am I missing anything here?

**UPDATE**

I had a look at the headers sent by the browser to the server and found out that `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET'] === null`

Comment: Read this site > http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Comment: What about your php->mysql connection? That has to be utf-8 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to submit of any other query via a given PHP MySQL link, try:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');
```

This statement indicates that further queries submit via the same MySQL link will be in UTF8 charset.

When you want to later retrieve the MySQL data and publish to a web page via PHP, be sure to set the charset in the HTTP header:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

...and convert to HTML entities in displayed content:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($mysql_col_str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

(this final statement assumes a variable **$mysql_col_str** has been defined which contains the UTF8 value returned by the MySQL query)

Comment: In Doctrine, is there a better way than `$entityManager_globalObject->getConnection()->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");` to do this? I ask because it seems to be generally recommended to avoid explicitly writing SQL like this in Doctrine...

Comment: And yes, using SET NAMES UTF8 worked for me, but I don't need to use mb_convert_encoding at all and drupal is already sending the right header info.

Comment: I have no experience with Doctrine so unable to advise on that front. Note that mb_convert_encoding() is not used prior to MySQL submittal, but to render the UTF-8 MySQL data content into HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding an extra parameter called charset to the configuration of the Entity Manager:

```
$conn = array(
  'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
  'host' => 'hostname',
  'user' => 'user',
  'password' => 'pass',
  'dbname' => 'dbname',
  'charset' => 'utf8'
);

$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```